# How to set the viewer environment to be local and log level to debug

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I saw in the viewer the following code:

```
avp.LogLevels = {
    DEBUG: 5,
    LOG: 4,
    INFO: 3,
    WARNING: 2,
    ERROR: 1,
    NONE: 0
};
```

And:

```
avp.initializeProtein = function () {

    //For local work, don't redirect texture requests to the CDN,
    //because local ones will load much faster, presumably.
    if (avp.ENABLE_DEBUG && avp.env == "Local" && !auth /* when auth is true, the viewer is operating under
```

How can I set `avp.env` to be Local and set the log level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at my blog post about [online/offline use of the viewer API](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/10/working-seamlessly-onlineoffline-when-developing-apps-with-the-forge-viewer-.html)

For log level use:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.logger.setLevel(5) //debug
```

Comment: What kind of information does the logger debug level give?

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize the viewer, pass the `env` and the `document` options as local resources.

```
function initialize() {
    var options = {
        'document' : './shaver/0.svf',
        'env':'Local'
        };

    var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');

    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerElement, {});

    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options,function() {
    viewer.initialize();
    viewer.load(options.document);
    });
}
```

Comment: So adding `LogLevels` to the options should set that too?

Comment: Also, I already have that in the settings but it doesn't go to this return: http://i.imgur.com/OT0b0Fs.png, are you sure it's the same `env`?